Uniformly Continuous and locally Lipschitz but not Globally Lipschitz Function on a "Connected but not compact" set
I know such a function exists but I can’t find an example. I have the famous example f:]0,inf[ --->R f(x)=sqrt(x) function. But I can't find any other function which is Uniformly Continuous and locally Lipschitz but not Globally Lipschitz (on a connected but not compact set) Can someone help me please?

You need to explain what you mean by another function? Translations, adding functions, etc, can easily create alternatives.

Another family of functions is $f_\alpha : (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f_\alpha(x)= x^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ (the proof that this functions do what you want is verbatim the same as for the square root function).
